# groupby week of date column in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am not understand group by clause in laravel
Query:

```
 DB::table('ipaddress')->select('date', DB::raw('count(id) as total'))
                       ->where('date','>=','now()-interval 6 week')
                       ->groupBy(DB::raw("WEEK(`date`)"))
                       ->get();
```

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'kitchen_portal.ipaddress.date' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `date`, count(id) as total from `ipaddress` where `date` >= now()-interval 6 week group by WEEK(`date`))

Comment: Please... update your question with queries and error details. Comments is not the right place for explain the issue.

Comment: now please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like below. There are rules for applying GROUP BY. You can only select a column which is Aggregated OR added in the GROUP BY clause. Here you add WEEK name in the GROUP BY but select directly the Date in the selection which is not allowed.

```
DB::table('ipaddress')->select(DB::raw("WEEK(`date`)"), DB::raw('count(id) as total'))
                      ->where('date','>=','now()-interval 6 week')
                      ->groupBy(DB::raw("WEEK(`date`)"))
                      ->get();
```

Comment: i don't want week no, i want first date

Comment: To get the MIN date per week, you can simply add a new column like - MIN(`Date`) in the select section.

Comment: Thanks, and also how i want to get month name with year which is month wise group?

Comment: MySQL has method to get MonthName as - MONTHNAME(NOW()). Try to use that in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `GROUP BY WEEK(date)`, then you need to use that in your select statement along with your aggregate function `COUNT()`.

You can never select more than what you `GROUP BY` (which here is `WEEK(date)`), plus aggregate functions such as `COUNT()`, `SUM()`, `MAX()` and so on. Introducing other values in your select statement can make your resultset return some odd combinations.

```php
DB::table('ipaddress')->select(DB::raw('WEEK(date) as WeekNo'), DB::raw('COUNT(id) as total'))
                      ->where('date', '>=', 'NOW() - INTERVAL 6 WEEK')
                      ->groupBy(DB::raw("WEEK(`date`)"))
                      ->get();
```